# Python code for creating FK Controllers error

Tags: python, maya

For the life of me I can't figure out why this script isn't working. If anyone can help it would be great.

The error I'm getting is # Error: invalid syntax #  and # Error: line 1: invalid syntax # .
But I can't see where my error is. It's probably staring me right in the face.
Thanks.

```
from maya import cmds

sel= cmds.ls(sl=1)
controller = None
preParent = None
for i in sel:
    cmds.select(cl=1)
    if controller == None or cmds.objExists(controller) == False:
        controller1 = cmds.circle( nr=(1, 0, 0 ), name = i+"CTRL")[0]
        else:
            controller1 = cmds.duplicate(controller, name = i +"CTRL")[0]

            grp = cmds.group(em = 1, name = i+"GRP")
            cmds.parent(controller1, grp)
            pc = cmds.parentConstraint(i, grp, mo=0)
            cmds.delete(pc)
            cmds.parentConstraint(controller1, i, mo=0)
            cmds.orientConstraint(controller1, i, mo=0)
            if preParent != None
            cmds.parent(grp, preParent)
            preParent = controller1
```

Comment: Not sure if that's formatting error here on Stack or is that also the case in your code but you don't have an indentation after the last if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's what it looks like in Maya if that helps https://www.dropbox.com/s/badeszu6i8txxd3/maya%20script.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the colon at the end of the code after the if statement.

Should be:

```
if preParent != None:
    cmds.parent(grp, preParent)
preParent = controller1
```

Comment: This did the trick and also my indent was the issue too so thanks to both of you. :)